# Merge selection with groups

Tags: d3.js, merge

I've worked out a consistent pattern for using the new selection merge which is brilliant for reusable charts where data and/or scales may change.

I've also been using the key function successfully.

However, I seem to get a problem when entering and appending a group with multiple elements.  The data is successfully updated in the group but not the appended elements.

I've got round it by adding a fix (see below) but I'm sure it is something really obvious that needs to be changed to resolve it.

Any thoughts?

```
//define data group 
var my_group = svg.selectAll(".data_group")
                  .data(my_data,function(d){return d.id});

//enter new groups
var enter = my_group.enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class","data_group");

//append items to group
enter.append("text").attr("class","group_item group_text")
enter.append("circle").attr("class","group_item group_circle");

//merge and remove
my_group.merge(enter);
my_group.exit().remove();

//fix added to reset changing data for bars.
d3.selectAll(".group_item").each(function(d){
  d3.select(this)._groups[0][0].__data__ = d3.select(this)._groups[0][0].parentElement.__data__;
});

d3.selectAll(".group_text")
  .... add properties to text - ie x,y,fill,text-anchor,text 

d3.selectAll(".group_circle")
     .... add properties to circle - ie cx,cy,fill,stroke,radius
```

Comment: your line `my_group.merge(enter);` has no purpose

Comment: without the "fix" I get the data bound to the `text` and the `circle`

Comment: Yes, but when you bind with different data it doesn't change until the fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no need for selecting the parent group, getting its data and rebinding it to the child elements, as the code in your question and the other answer do. This is bending over backwards. Also, do not delete/re-append elements, as suggested, which is **not** an idiomatic D3 approach.

The thing is simple: the new data is there for the children elements in the "enter" selection. You just need to use the parent's selection (with `select()`) to propagate them.

Here is a basic demo, using (most of) your code. The code generates from 1 to 5 data objects, with a random property called `someProperty`. You'll see that, using your `each()`, only the children elements in the "enter" selection are changed:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
d3.interval(function() {
  var data = d3.range(1 + ~~(Math.random() * 4)).map(function(d) {
    return {
      id: "id" + d,
      "someProperty": ~~(Math.random() * 100)
    }
  });
  update(data);
}, 2000);

function update(my_data) {
  var my_group = svg.selectAll(".data_group")
    .data(my_data, function(d) {
      return d.id
    });

  my_group.exit().remove();

  var enter = my_group.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "data_group");

  enter.append("text").attr("class", "group_item group_text")
  enter.append("circle").attr("class", "group_item group_circle");

  my_group = my_group.merge(enter);


  console.log("---")

  d3.selectAll(".group_text").each(function(d) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(d))
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Now, if we use your parent's selection...

```
my_group.select(".group_text").each(function(d) {
    console.log(d)
})
```

... you'll see that **all** properties are updated:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
d3.interval(function() {
  var data = d3.range(1 + ~~(Math.random() * 4)).map(function(d) {
    return {
      id: "id" + d,
      "someProperty": ~~(Math.random() * 100)
    }
  });
  update(data);
}, 2000);

function update(my_data) {
  var my_group = svg.selectAll(".data_group")
    .data(my_data, function(d) {
      return d.id
    });

  my_group.exit().remove();

  var enter = my_group.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "data_group");

  enter.append("text").attr("class", "group_item group_text")
  enter.append("circle").attr("class", "group_item group_circle");

  my_group = my_group.merge(enter);


  console.log("---")

  my_group.select(".group_text").each(function(d) {
    console.log(d)
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Finally, in your now deleted answer you're using `my_group.selectAll()`. The problem is that `selectAll()` does not propagate the data.

Have a look at this table I made:

| Method | select() | selectAll() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selection | selects the first element that matches the selector string | selects all elements that match the selector string |
| Grouping | Does not affect grouping | Affects grouping |
| Data propagation | Propagates data | Doesn't propagate data |

Pay attention to the *propagates data* versus *doesn't propagate data*.

Answer (score 0):

The more d3 way of copying the data bound to the parent `g` elements

**No need to add the fix**

```
d3.selectAll(".group_text")
    .datum(function () { return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum(); } )
    //   .... add properties to text - ie x,y,fill,text-anchor,text 

d3.selectAll(".group_circle")
    .datum(function () { return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum(); } )
    //   .... add properties to circle - ie cx,cy,fill,stroke,radius
```

Comment: I'm just sure there must be a neater way though - neither are 100% d3 approach are they.

Comment: @Bmil: it is not advised to use the `__data__` variable, it is not part of the API and can change without notice, the `.datum()` is the way to get/set the bound data of an element. there is AFAIK no API to distribute the data to all children because not all children want the data but a derived or a field version. What you can do is delete all `text` and `circle` and add them new to the `g` elements. If it is not thousands then there is no problem.

Comment: Thanks Rio.  I know you can delete them but that is the old way!  I'm being a purist.  I'll switch to datum on your advice but would still be interested to know if anyone else out there has a better way...

Comment: @Bmil: that is not true. Because you can do it doesn't mean you have to do it. If deleting is simpler and does not take a lot of time do it.